# vb.net deserialize an xml string

Tags: xml, vb.net, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I've got a simple xml string that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AccountBalance>
    <value>
        22.00
    </value>
</AccountBalance>
```

I'd like to set the value of `<value>` to a variable in vb.net. How do I do this?

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with serialization.  Are you asking how to get the value of `<value>` from the XML?

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where serialization comes into play for this, but if it's just a simple XML string you can use LINQ to XML to get the value quite easily:

```
Dim xml As XElement = New XElement.Parse(xmlString)

Dim Balance As Integer = From x in xml.Descendants("value")
                         Select CInt(x.Value)
```

This will give you a collection of the value elements in the XML.  If you only have one, you can also do this:

```
Dim Balance As Integer = (From x in xml.Descendants(xmlString)
                         Select  CInt(x.Value)).SingleOrDefault()
```

xmlString is the XML string you want to get values from - the `Parse` method loads the xml from a supplied string.  Use `.Load` if it's in a file.

Syntax might be a bit off - I'm doing this off the top of my head.

Comment: Should be `Dim xml As XElement = New XElement.Parse(xmlString)` but other than that it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to pass the XML as a Stream, TextReader, or XmlReader? 
Please refer to this [XmlSerializer.Deserialize Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cca2d5s9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)